# cs50 dna when i debug my code i got this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cs50

this is  my code
ok **i know my code have o^234234324 complexity algorithmically** but
its work for all sequences except sequences/15.txt and  sequences/16.txt

```
import sys
import csv
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("useage: filenameofdata.cvs filenameofsequence.txt")
    sys.exit(1)
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as datafile:
    readdata = list(csv.reader(datafile))
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as sequencefile:
    readsequence = list(csv.reader(sequencefile))
strs = list(readdata[0][1:])
conlist = []
dnanum = 0
for move in (strs):
    sequence = list(readsequence[0][0])
    consecutively = 0
    l = len(move)
    cursor = [None] * 2
    temp = [None] * l
    x = 0
    counter = 0
    while counter == 0:
        if sequence == []:
            conlist.append(consecutively)
            break
        for oneletter in (sequence):
            if x < 2:
                cursor[x] = oneletter
            temp[x] = oneletter
            x += 1
            if x == l:
                asstring = ''.join(map(str, temp))
                if asstring == move:
                    dnanum += 1
                    move
                    temp = [None] * l
                    x = 0
                    continue
                else:
                    if consecutively < dnanum:
                        consecutively = dnanum
                    oneletter = sequence.remove(cursor[0])
                    temp = [None] * l
                    x = 0
                    dnanum = 0
                    break
# this print was for check if i got the right str consecutively
print(conlist)
conlist = ''.join(map(str, conlist))
for y in readdata:
    x = ''.join(map(str, y[1:]))
    if conlist == x:
        print(y[0])
        sys.exit(1)
print("No match")
```

when i try debug it in  sequences/15.txt and  sequences/16.txt or if i try to run them i got no output
the massage error when debug

```
~/pset6/dna/ $ debug50 python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/15.txt                                                                                                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ikp3db.py", line 2105, in <module>
    ikp3db.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ikp3db.py", line 2011, in main
    debug_socket.bind((cmd_line_args.IKPDB_ADDRESS, cmd_line_args.IKPDB_PORT,))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @VedantMehta Mehta  i'm trying to read sequences of someone dna and comparing it on database they gave ( identifies a person based on their DNA )

Comment: errors means that program uses socket (network connection) and it tried to use IP:PORT which is already used. It can means that other program uses it and you would have to find this program and close it. Or socket wasn't correctly closed/disconected when it was used previous time and now system will block this IP:PORT for few seconds/minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too complicated. To get maximum number of consecutive STRs for each STR, I only write 6 lines of code:

```
for i in range(1, len(data[0])):  # loop through all STR

    count = 1

    string = data[0][i]  # assign each STR to a string

    while string * count in dna:  # if find 1 string, then try to find string*2, and so on

        count += 1

    counts.append(str(count - 1))  # should be decreased by 1 as initialized to 1
```